# Method should throw exception but it doesn't

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I wrote a small extensionmethod which finds the indexes of the given string in any IEnumerable.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexesOf(this IEnumerable<string> itemList, string indexesToFind)
{
    if (itemList == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("itemList");
    if (indexesToFind == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("indexToFind");

    List<string> enumerable = itemList as List<string> ?? itemList.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < enumerable.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (enumerable[i] == indexesToFind)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

As you can see above, an ArgumentNullException is thrown if itemList is null. Plain and simple.

When running my unittest on the above method, I expect and exception of type ArgumentNullException, because itemList is null. However, the test comes out false because no exception gets thrown.

How is that possible? The logic seems quite clear. See the test below.

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void FindIndexesOfTest2()
{
    string[] items = null;
    IEnumerable<int> indexes = items.FindIndexesOf("one");
}
```

Where am I going wrong in my logic; why is it not throwing an ArgumentNullException?

Comment: Have you run the code in debugger and checked whether the parameter is really null?

Comment: I have, yes. It is actually null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that enumerators using `yield` is lazily evaluated.

Since you're not iterating over the collection returned, the method hasn't actually executed.

The correct way to do this is to split the method in two:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexesOf(this IEnumerable<string> itemList, string indexesToFind)
{
    if (itemList == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("itemList");
    if (indexesToFind == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("indexToFind");

    return FindIndexesOfImpl(itemList, indexesToFind);    
}

private static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexesOfImpl(this IEnumerable<string> itemList, string indexesToFind)
{
    List<string> enumerable = itemList as List<string> ?? itemList.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < enumerable.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (enumerable[i] == indexesToFind)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

Here the first method will execute when you call it, and return a lazily evaluated enumerator that hasn't, until you iterate over it.

Though, I would suggest you also change the latter method here to be truly lazily evaluated. The fact that the method caches the entire `itemList` just to be able to use indexes is unnecessary, and you can in fact rewrite it without it:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexesOfImpl(this IEnumerable<string> itemList, string indexesToFind)
{
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var item in itemList)
    {
        if (item == indexesToFind)
            yield return index;
        index++;
    }
}
```

You can also use the LINQ extension methods to do it though this involves constructing a temporary object for each element, unsure whether it is worth it, I'd go with the one just above here instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexesOfImpl(this IEnumerable<string> itemList, string indexesToFind)
{
    return itemList
        .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
        .Where(element => element.item == indexesToFind)
        .Select(element => element.index);
}
```

With this last method you can move this back up into the main method because you're no longer using `yield`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindIndexesOf(this IEnumerable<string> itemList, string indexesToFind)
{
    if (itemList == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("itemList");
    if (indexesToFind == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("indexToFind");

    return itemList
        .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
        .Where(element => element.item == indexesToFind)
        .Select(element => element.index);
}
```

Comment: Works, you're the best!

Comment: Note that it may actually be better to just construct a list in the method and return that, containing the results, instead of using an enumerator here, since you're in fact caching the entire `itemList` anyway. There's a different way to write that last method though without the need for a cache, I'll post that as well.

Comment: Which of these two would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend either the one using `foreach` and the `index` variable, or that last one, which is back to only 1 method.

Comment: Yes, but which one of those? What are the benefits to both of them?

Comment: Both will be truly lazily, and not consume the entire input collection before moving on, which means you can pipe in something that reads from a huge file without having to cache the entire file in memory.

Comment: Personally I would recommend the one using `foreach` with the `index` variable. Personally I find that one easier to read compared to the extension methods in the last one. Also, the last method will construct a temporary object around the item+index, which may add some overhead. So I would go with the `foreach/index` method.

Comment: That was my initial thought. Thanks again!

Comment: The benefit of the last one is of course that you have put all the code back into one method. That may be worth something as well, but again, my *personal recommendation* is to go with the other one.